# How to rename the name of project in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have to remame the projcet name from AAA to BBB in VS2010. What can I do?

Answer (score 37):

To rename every detail of a project:

1. Right-click and rename the project in Solution Explorer.
2. Right-click and rename any related .cpp and .h files.
3. Right-click the project and select "Remove".  Confirm saving any changed files.
4. Exit Visual Studio.
5. Rename the project's directory.
6. Rename the project's .vcxproj and .vcxproj.filters files.
7. Search the project's folder for any references to the old project name in file contents. 
   Typical places are:

   - Comments in the project's main .cpp file.
   - Comments in stdafx.cpp.
   - A <RootNamespace> entry in the project's .vcxproj file.
8. Start Visual Studio and load the .sln file.
9. Right-click the solution and add the project again.
10. Put some thought into new project names so you don't have to do this again :^)

Comment: "Put some thought into new project names so you don't have to do this again :^)" the OP might be starting a new project from an old one

Comment: I would add, I've done this a couple of times before, and both times I had issues getting the filters to work because the project file name had got mangled and it was different to the filters file name - for instance my project became myproject.vcxproj.vcxproj whereas my filter remained myproject.vcxproj.filters. Renaming the project fixed this. I'm not sure what caused the filename to become mangled in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Select the project node in Solution Explorer, then click on its name again -- just like you would rename anything in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work.... but then you realize that there are references to the project name everywhere and none of them were updated.

Comment: @EdS., oops, I didn't notice that this was a C++ question. (The references get updated just fine when you rename a C# project this way, but I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work for a C++ project.)